# VBA Alignment of text within a textbox

Tags: vba

I wants to know got any way to display a text inside the textbox together with align left and right.
The textbox property just only left or right.
Example:

[image]

Comment: Use a fixed width (non-proportional) font and right pad the first value with spaces to a fixed length.

Comment: why don't you just use 2 textboxes. or is it part of your requirement to only use 1?

Comment: Any idea how to fixed the length?
Because i will have the scroll bar,the filename and the date should be in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to align amount with 3 decimal places in the right of a text box. The string variable I use is addnreport.

I used a temporary string StrX which I RSet (Right Pad)
In atext editor, it shows up as expected but in the Text Box, the values on the extreme right seem to be centre aligned no matter what you do.

```
addnreport = addnreport & acc & vbTab & month & vbTab & "PL" 
            RSet StrX = (Format(Round(amount, 3), "#,###,###,##0.000"))
            addnreport = addnreport & StrX & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add tab char for this,

- set default textbox alignment to left,
- in code behind add first word
- in code behind add tab char
- in code behind add second word
- display it in your textbox

hope it work